# Cannot add Anypoint Platform authentication to Anypoint Studio in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, anypoint-studio

I am trying to add authentication for the Anypoint Platform in a mule project in Anypoint Studio Using: Anypoint platform --> Configure --> Authentication --> Add.

The interface for entering username/passord appears as expected and the login is working.

But I am unable to add and store the authentication to be used. I am getting the Anypoint Platform website in the dialog window.

Below is a screenshot of what is shown after login, so no where to select the user as expected.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and Anypoint Studio 6.1.2
But I have seen this on many combinations of Ubuntu and Anypoint Studio, I have not gotten it working yet.

Have anyone gotten this working in Ubuntu??

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFw1Z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 and anypoint studio 6.1.0 is working fine, but after updating anypoint studio, authentication is no longer working.

The authentication all ready done is however still valid.

So i quess this is a bug in anypoint studio 6.1.2 and on....