# Why anypoint platform is not able to authenticate from anypoint studio 7.3.1 for deployment on CloudHub?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

**Problem**

In the learning of Mule 4, I have to deploy project to CoudHub from Anypoint Studio 7.3.1 in Windows 10.

Taken the following steps in Anypoint Studio 7.3.1:

Right clicked the project in package explorer>Anypoint Platform> Deploy to CloudHub; Following screen appeared

[image]

I entered the credentials, then the following screen appeared

[image]

**Workarounds tried**

1) tried with the mates account, same problem.

2) updated anypoint studio, but not good happened.

3) tried restarting anypoint studio as well as laptop.

4) browsed the following links but couldn't find any solution

[Cannot add Anypoint Platform authentication to Anypoint Studio in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956378/cannot-add-anypoint-platform-authentication-to-anypoint-studio-in-ubuntu)

[While trying to configure Mulesoft Anypoint studio with Anypoint platform it's giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054876/while-trying-to-configure-mulesoft-anypoint-studio-with-anypoint-platform-its-g)

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/100885/i-am-not-able-to-connect-to-anypoint-platform-from.html